# How Do I Set these Anonymous Classes Up in Java?

Tags: java, anonymous-class

Okay, so recently I decompiled some code I had written years ago. So, the decompiler I use does not decompile the anonymous classes, since the Java compiler compiled them as separate classes.

So, I have a file called TitleScreen, and other files following with TitleScreen$1, TitleScreen$2. Simple. But....why the numbers? The class isn't named with an int, that's impossible. How would these be structured? Do I just give them a random name like optionsClick(), worldsClick()?

Thanks!

Comment: Those are usually inner classes

Comment: "The class isn't named with an int, that's impossible" Try defining a class explicitly called `TitleScreen$1`. It is a valid (but unusual) name.

Comment: @AndyTurner Ah, okay, thank you! Didn't know that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are the names the Java compiler generates for anonymous classes.

You can give them whatever name you want.

Comment: Ah, yes, that did seem to be okay. I wasn't sure because it's been years since I've worked with nested classes a lot, didn't know if they had to be name specific or not. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is more powerful than us mere programmers and can name classes with that funny syntax.  Perhaps it does it that way cause it knows it is "safe": no user defined class (see comments below) is likely to have that name.

As for what you should name the decompiled classes, I'd suggest TitleScreen.Anon1, TitleScreen.Anon2 if you make them inner classes, or TitleScreen_Anon1 if their own classes.   That way you have some reference back to the original code if needed.

Comment: Why can't a user-defined class have that name?!

Comment: OK, let me elaborate: no sane user defined class that follows any coding style guide in the known universe can have that name.  :-)

Comment: s/can/should/, certainly